# Getting user input for os.system

Tags: python, os.system

Only recently started to learn Python, so please excuse the noob question (might be doing this completely wrong to begin with)

I'm trying to get user input to use with `os.system`

```
import os
account = input("Account name: ")
os.system("op get item + account + | awk -F':' '{print $24}' | cut -d '}' -f 1")
```

this line of code is used to take and display the information from 1Password and outputs just
the password of Facebook is this example, it works but as soon as i try to add the variable it breaks

```
op get item Facebook | awk -F':' '{print $24}' | cut -d '}' -f 1
```

I hope someone here can help me out or point me in the right direction, thanks!

Comment: `os.system("op get item "+account+" | awk -F':' '{print $24}' | cut -d '}' -f 1")`

Comment: Can you share the entire line you tried, including the `os.system()` ?

Comment: thanks a lot, this seems to work perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You just need string substitution, e.g. with Python3.6+ the elegant

```
os.system(f"op get item {account} | awk -F':'" + " '{print $24}' | cut -d '}' -f 1")
```

Comment: Why do you need the `+`? Also, a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` will happen due to `{print $24}`

Comment: That's precisely why I used the `+`, duh

Comment: Oh, I good point, I thought "+" before account was part of the command. Went too quick. Now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to work with the output of these commands, so you can use the subprocess module instead: [Replacing Shell Pipeline](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline)

For example:

```py
from subprocess import check_output

check_output(f"op get item {account} | awk -F':' '{{print $24}}' | cut -d '}}' -f 1", shell=True)
```

Be aware that you would like to sanitize the account variable, before touching your system calls. :)

Comment: thanks for the link, I'll get into it! for now, just changing + account + to "+account+" seems to do the trick